# c++ error std::result_of does not name a type

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, g++, result-of

After `g++ -std=c++0x`'ing `std::result_of` produces the following error message

```
error: ‘result_of’ in namespace ‘std’ does not name a type
```

(g++ version 4.5.0 on SUSE.)

The relevant piece of code, sufficient for reproducing the error is below

```
#include <random>
#include <type_traits>

using namespace std;

class Rnd{
protected:
  static default_random_engine generator_;
};

template<class distribution>
class Distr: Rnd{
  distribution distribution_;
public:
  typename std::result_of<distribution(default_random_engine)>::type 
       operator() (){ return distribution_(default_random_engine); }
};
```

Moreover, I have tried to compile examples from wikipedia or cpluplus.com to no avail.
Is it a problem with the particular compiler or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: g++ 4.6.3 doesn't complain about `result_of` (it complains about the code afterwards, however), so maybe it's just not yet implemented in your version, and you need to upgrade the compiler.

Comment: And looking closer on your code, I also see the error g++ 4.6.3 complains about: you are passing a type instead of an object to `operator()` of the member object `distribution_` (I guess you wanted to pass `generator_`).

Comment: @celtschk. Yes, of course, I am passing the `generator_`. Just a "typo".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to include `<functional>` also. gcc 4.5 is based on an older version of C++11, in which `std::result_of` is defined in `<functional>` instead of `<type_traits>`.

This move was introduced in [n3090](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3090.pdf) (2010 March 29) after fixing [issue 1270](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#1270). gcc 4.5.0 was released just 16 days after the change  [(2010 April 14)](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.5/), which did not have enough time to apply, as we can see from [this online source code](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/libstdc++-api-4.5/a00875_source.html#l00172) of `<functional>`.

`std::result_of` was moved to `<type_traits>` in [gcc 4.6](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/libstdc++-api-4.6/a01093_source.html#l01139).